# How vtable pointer is chosen among other vtable pointers in a class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I am quite interested about `virtual inheritance` and this thing creates mystery for me. Let's consider an example with `virtual inheritance`:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void v() { std::cout << "v"; }
};

struct IntermediateDerivedFirst : virtual Base {
    virtual void w() { std::cout << "w"; }
};

struct IntermediateDerivedSecond : virtual Base {
    virtual void x() { std::cout << "x"; }
};

struct Derived : IntermediateDerivedFirst, IntermediateDerivedSecond {
    virtual void y() { std::cout << "y"; }
};
```

Finally, `Derived` should look like this:

```
 --------
|[vtable]| -----> [ vbase offset 20               ]
|[vtable]|---     [ top offset    0               ]
|[vtable]|- |     [ Derived typeinfo              ]
 --------  ||     [ IntermediateDerivedFirst::w() ]
           ||     [ Derived::y()                  ]
           ||
           |----> [ vbase offset 12               ]
           |      [ top offset   -8               ]
           |      [ Derived typeinfo              ]
           |      [ IntermediateDerivedSecond::x()]
           |
           -----> [ vbase offset 0               ]
                  [ top offset   -20             ]
                  [ Derived typeinfo             ]
                  [ Base::v()                    ]
```

So, literally, `virtual` inheritance moves `vtable` for the most base class to the end and as we can see -- `vtable`s for `IntermediateDerivedFirst`, `IntermediateDerivedSecond` do not contain address for `Base`'s `v()` method. Okay, then, we can see that the class has few `vtable`s.
Let's consider a code:

```
IntermediateDerivedFirst* fb = new Derived;
fb->v();
delete fb;
```

This invocation is still valid, **however**, `vtable` for `IntermediateDerivedFirst` has no info about `v()` method and it seems it uses some magic here and it uses third `vtable` pointer to invoke `v()`.
So, how does the compiler choose needed `vtable` pointer to get an address of function being invoked?

Comment: That is an implementation detail. One possibility is that the virtual function call includes the an offset so that "this" points properly at the one copy of `Base` (or whatever class implements the virtual function).

Comment: You might be interested in the book "Inside the C++ Object Model" by Lippman. It goes into such implementation details in great depth.

Comment: What makes you believe that the layout of `Derived` is as you describe? How did you determine that? It doesn't look plausible to me - normally, the vtable of the most-derived class contains pointers to virtual functions from all the base classes. So I fully expect the vtable of `IntermediateDerivedFirst` instance to contain a pointer to `Base::v` implementation.

Comment: By the way, `delete fb;` in your example exhibits undefined behavior, by way of deleting an instance of a class without virtual destructor through a pointer to its base class.

Comment: I know about UB. I omitted virtual destructor to get my example simpler

Comment: I think you interpretation is not correct if we are talking the most used compilers. Derived [won't have 3 vtable pointers](https://godbolt.org/z/E3q3Kfz1j) in most common implementations. It will has only 2, because it has only 2 _direct_ base classes. In my understanding the vtable of `Derived` is used for calling the virtual functions of its first _direct_ base class (`IntermediateDerivedFirst`) and its base classes (`Base`). And `Derived` stores a second vtable pointer for its second _direct_ base class (`IntermediateDerivedSecond`) and its base classes (`Base`).

Comment: Sorry, offering a bounty doesn't change the fact that the layout of vtables (or even, theoretically, the existence of vtables since, although a common implementation approach, the standard does not require vtables) is highly compiler-specific.   That means there is no canonical answer to your question as asked.   What you say "`Derived` should look like" is not required at all by the C++ standard.   If you're looking for an answer specific to a particular compiler, then you need to identify that compiler, and focus the question/tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bjarne Stroustroup wrote a detailed paper on solving the "diamond problem" in multiple inheritance using C++:
[Stroustrup, B Fall 1989, 'Multiple Inheritance for C++'. *Computing Systems*, Vol. 2 No. 4, p. 367-395](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/publications/compsystems/1989/fall_stroustrup.pdf)

With the 'virtual Base' declared in both IntermediateDerived classes; you are guaranteed to get only a single instance of the common Base class.

From [C++ Language / Classes / Derived classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/derived_class)

> For each distinct base class that is specified virtual, the most derived object contains only one base class subobject of that type, even if the class appears many times in the inheritance hierarchy (as long as it is inherited virtual every time).

That is the compiler will provide one instance of each:

- Derived
- IntermediateDerivedFirst
- IntermediateDerivedSecond
- Base

Both the IntermediateDerived_X classes will have a **virtual pointer** in their vtables that stores the offset to the Base class. When either IntermediateDerived_X class attempts to access Base::v(), it uses the **virtual pointer** in it's vtable to find the Base object. Along this same line; if Derived inherited 100 more IntermediateDerived_X classes with the same 'virtual Base,' there would still only ever be one Base instance.
The call to Base::v() function uses the virtual pointer to access the instance of the Base class.

It is important to note that the Base object is only constructed once; when it is first initialized in the Derived class. Inherited classes will be constructed from Base to most derived. Conversely; the order of destruction will go from most derived to Base
In the example instantiation; calling 'new Derived' will construct a single instance of each of the four classes is constructed.

Based on the address table above: IntermediateDerivedFirst has knowledge of 'vbase offset = 20', which is the location of the Base object vtable. IntermediateDerivedSecond could access the Base class in the same way (vbase offset = 12); and would result in the exact same functionality.  ***There is not a magic third vtable, but simply a pointer to the vtable of Base shared between all derived classes.***

From an implementation viewpoint; it is generally more memory savvy to add a single pointer to a Base class in all virtual classes than it would be to copy the virtual table to every derived class. Different compilers, optimizations, linkers etc. may implement or change the resulting vtables a little differently. But there will only be a single Base object pointed to by all derived classes using virtual inheritance.